# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" on Easy Dots Scroll library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I'm using the Easy Dots Scroll library created by a developer that I downloaded from github on a website project, the three scroll dots appear on the side but when I click on any of them to jump to the section on the website denoted by the dots it doesn't work, in the console I get the error
`script2.js:184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Checking the code in the console this is the part of the code that contains the error

`

```
function scrollIndiClicked(indiId) {
   

     if (window.jQuery) {
            // if jquery is availble then we can use jquery animations
            if (dotFixedNavPresent === true && dotFixedNavId.length) {
                // there is a fixed nav and its id has been defined
                const dotNavHeightElem = document.getElementById(dotFixedNavId);
                const dotNavHeight = dotNavHeightElem.clientHeight;
                const dotDocumentHtml = $('html, body');
                const indiElement = $('#' + indiId);
        
                if (dotFixedNavUp === true) {
                    // fix nav on upward scroll only
                    dotDocumentHtml.animate({
                        scrollTop: indiElement.offset().top
                    }, 700);
                    const scrollPos = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top > scrollPos) {
                            dotDocumentHtml.animate({
                                scrollTop: indiElement.offset().top - dotNavHeight
                            }, 400);
                        }
                    }, 400);
                }
                else {
                    // fixed nav scroll
                    dotDocumentHtml.animate({
                        scrollTop: indiElement.offset().top - dotNavHeight
                    }, 700);
                }
            }
            else {
                // normal scroll
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#' + indiId).offset().top
                }, 700);
            }    
        }
        else {
```

`

more specifically the error is coming from the top property here

` // normal scroll

```
  $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + indiId).offset().top
        }, 700);
```

`

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the tag $('#' + indiId) exists?

Comment: Where is your code located? Header or Footer? I'm guessing your scripts are in your header, since `indiElement` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @disinfor it's in the footer just above the closing body tag.

Comment: We'll need your HTML to help you. We don't need all of it, but a minimal example.